# Is "Relevant Knowledge" spyware?

Tags: spyware, trojan, avast

I am an advanced user, using Windows 7 with [Avast!](http://www.avast.com/index) antivirus running.
Today I started browsing and faced some weird popup. Upon investigation I found that "Relevant Knowledge" was running in my system.

I was able to uninstall it using the Programs Manager and deleted the file's entries in the registry, but I am a little troubled due to the fact that Avast! was not able to detect it; and secondly, how it came into my system.

Also, what further prevention measures should I take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am a little troubled due to the fact that Avast was not able to detect it.

Malware is getting better and better :( It is highly likely it was delivered to your machine as an add-on to a third party (free) program, or it could have been from a zero-day vulnerability in a program such as Flash or Java.

> 2ndly how it came into my system. plus what further preventation should i take?

If you were able to find and remove it, you are already safer than the average person. Just be careful when downloading applications and always uncheck optional components that come with it. If you want to double check your system, I recommend using [Malware Bytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/malwarebytes_pro)...

Unfortunately, if you don't know how it came on your system in the first place, you can't defend against it.

Comment: Malware Bytes is a good call it has detected the remains of Relevant knowledge in temp files and removed it.

Answer (score 1):

**Relevantknowledge is not a virus**

I think spyware is not the right term because this software is installed with the user's knowledge and permission and can be uninstalled easily from the Control Panel. I believe that it is not malicious. It is just a program that gathers some information about user's browsing  habits, thus making it a "genuine" piece of software.